# In HMS plugin Documentation, you discuss about HMS manager prefab.....but in your HMS plugin content there is no prefab named "HMS manager" prefab

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Feel free to use this quick reply template to facilitate your feedback handling.

1. What were you doing when you ran into the problem?
   Answer: no reward wii recive....and ads not recive........as shown in refrence ppic below errors are come out when project is run
2. At which step did the problem occur?
   Answer:
   In HMS plugin Documentation, you discuss about HMS manager prefab.....but in your HMS plugin content there is no prefab named "HMS manager" prefab......what should we drag in our scene to link our project to HMS services
3. What were you expecting?
   Answer:
4. What actually happened?
   Answer:
5. What are the model and OS version of the device you were using?
   Answer:
6. What are the versions of the integrated kit SDK and AREngine (if any)?
   Answer:
7. Paste a screenshot if what you saw when the problem occurred.
   Answer:
8. Or upload it by clicking on the picture icon above.
   Answer:

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There are different prefabs for different HMS kits and prefabs contain their own scripts as shown above.
For example, if you want to use ads kit, you should add 'AdsManager' prefab. AdsManager prefab has different scripts like RewardAdManager, InterstitalAdManager, BannerAdManager.
You'll need to deploy the needed HMS kit prefab inside your scene.
Please check this link for [integration steps](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0202351212430530167?fid=0101187876626530001)